# How to get the area of a polygon explicitly written?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to get the area of explicitly written polygon without any success.

```
SELECT SDO.GEOM.SDO_AREA('POLYGON ((...))')
```

`...` contains my polygon values

I'm getting error:

```
SQL Error [923] [42000]: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

How can I write my polygon in the `select` query and get the `area` of this polygon ?

Comment: Does your query have a `from` clause?  That's required in Oracle syntax.  You could `select ... from dual` if you just want a 1-row table to query.  If this is in PL/SQL, you could just assign the value to the local variable rather than doing a `select ... into`.

Answer (score 0):

- It is `SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA` and not `SDO.GEOM.SDO_AREA`.
- You need to pass a `SDO_GEOMETRY` object as the first argument and not a string (containing a GIS shape).
- You need a second argument containing the tolerance (or a `SDO_DIM_ARRAY`).
- You need a `FROM` clause and a table to select from (`DUAL` is usually used if you only want a single row).
- You need to pass a valid GIS shape; `...` is not valid.

Like this:

```sql
SELECT SDO_GEOM.SDO_AREA(
         SDO_GEOMETRY('POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0))'),
         0.0000000005
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f541bc18e0a24f6ea5a2a310d3786c4d)*